# Redshift access to only few columns in a view

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a view which is based on another view.

Example :

```
create or replace view old_view as select * from new_view
```

I don't want user to have access to all the columns in the `old_view`.

The `new_view` contains lots of PII data and since the `old_view` is based on the `new_view`,
I want specific user to NOT have access to some of the columns in the `old_view`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `SELECT * FROM new_view`, you should include the list of columns that you specifically want to include in the view, eg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE old_view AS SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM new_view
```

This way, `old_view` will only contain the columns you allow and the user won't be able to access other columns (assuming that they are not permitted to access `new_view`).

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE old_view AS SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM new_view.

I'm getting this error when I try to grant the access

GRANT SELECT( col1,col2,col3)    
ON  new_view TO db_user;

SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "col1" of relation "new_view" does not exist

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `GRANT SELECT ON old_view TO db_user`? Or if you want to specify columns for column-level privileges, make sure the column names match the actual column names. In fact, given that Redshift has column-level privileges, you could probably grant access to the table directly, without needing to use a View.